# Cant delete objects from AWS S3 bucket that usees CloudFront distribution

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, security

I'm trying to to add an option on my website to be able to delete objects from my s3 bucket that is using CloudFront. I am getting error, Attempting to delete * Error Access Denied. Which is strange because I can upload files to the bucket just fine using similar code, the uploaded objects use SSE-S3 encyrption. The code I'm using to delete an object:

```
 require './vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$bucket = '-';
$keyname = $_POST['-'];
 $IAM_KEY = '-';
 $IAM_SECRET = '-';
 try {

   $s3 = S3Client::factory(
     array(
       'credentials' => array(
         'key' => $IAM_KEY,
         'secret' => $IAM_SECRET
       ),
       'version' => 'latest',
       'region'  => 'eu-west-2'
     )
   );
 } catch (Exception $e) {

   die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
 }
// 1. Delete the object from the bucket.
try
{
   echo 'Attempting to delete ' . $keyname . '...' . PHP_EOL;

   $result = $s3->deleteObject([
       'Bucket' => $bucket,
       'Key'    => $keyname
   ]);

   if ($result['DeleteMarker'])
   {
       echo $keyname . ' was deleted or does not exist.' . PHP_EOL;
   } else {
       exit('Error: ' . $keyname . ' was not deleted.' . PHP_EOL);
   }
}
catch (S3Exception $e) {
   exit('Error: ' . $e->getAwsErrorMessage() . PHP_EOL);
}

// 2. Check to see if the object was deleted.
try
{
   echo 'Checking to see if ' . $keyname . ' still exists...' . PHP_EOL;

   $result = $s3->getObject([
       'Bucket' => $bucket,
       'Key'    => $keyname
   ]);

   echo 'Error: ' . $keyname . ' still exists.';
}
catch (S3Exception $e) {
   exit($e->getAwsErrorMessage());
}
```

My bucket policy:

```
{
   "Version": "2008-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Principal": {
               "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity -"
           },
           "Action": [
               "s3:PutObject",
               "s3:PutObjectAcl",
               "s3:GetObject",
               "s3:GetObjectAcl",
               "s3:GetObjectVersion",
               "s3:DeleteObject",
               "s3:DeleteObjectVersion"
           ],
           "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::-/*"
       }
   ]
}
```

My cors:

```
[
   {
       "AllowedHeaders": [
           "*"
       ],
       "AllowedMethods": [
           "GET",
           "PUT",
           "DELETE"
       ],
       "AllowedOrigins": [
           "*"
       ],
       "ExposeHeaders": [
           "ETag"
       ]
   }
]
```

IAM key json

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
               "s3:PutObject",
               "s3:GetObject"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:s3:::*"
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Why am I getting an error if I am providing my IAM key and secret and my bucket policy allows deletion ?

Comment: Your bucket policy only applies to Cloudfront's access; `$s3->deleteObject` doesn't go through CloudFront at all. What policy is applied to *your* IAM key?

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: This is my IAM KEY Json

Comment: You are using the SDK, which goes directly to the S3 API, not through Cloudfront, and since you don't have the permissions `s3:DeleteObject`, it fails. If you want to hit your distribution, you need to send HTTP requests to the distribution domain alias.

Comment: How can I do that ? @palvarez

Comment: You probably shouldn't. You should add `s3:DeleteObject` to the IAM key's policy.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `$s3->deleteObject` doesn't involve CloudFront at all.

It's made directly to S3, using *your* IAM key, not CloudFront's. As such, your personal IAM user/role requires the `s3:DeleteObject` permission be added to its policy for this code to function.

Comment: I have amended the IAM Json and added s3:DeleteObject. Now I am getting the following:
Attempting to delete -... 
- was deleted or does not exist. 
Checking to see if - still exists... 
Access Denied

Comment: Print out the full `$result` and see what it contains.

Comment: I'll keep looking, could be a typoi

Comment: Model Data ---------- Data can be retrieved from the model object using the get() method of the model (e.g., `$result->get($key)`)or "accessing the result like an associative array (e.g. `$result['key']`). You can also execute JMESPath expressions on the result data using the search() method. { "DeleteMarker": true, "VersionId

Comment: This is what I'm getting after printing out $result ^^

Comment: `DeleteMarker: true` means it worked, right?

Comment: Ill tick you answer as correct as you have indeed answered my initial question.

Comment: No, I checked s3 and file still exists

Comment: To test if an object exists, you typically need the s3:s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket ARN resource. Otherwise the underlying HeadObject call will return 403 (access denied), instead of 404 (not found).

Comment: Typo: I meant `s3:ListBucket`, of course.