# Can't delete bucket object with s3:DeleteObject policy set

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I have a private S3 bucket (let's call it `test-bucket`) with all public accesses blocked, and a CloudFront distribution that serves it.

My web application has an IAM user to programmatically access AWS resources, to which I attached the managed authorisation policy `AmazonS3FullAccess`.

I have also set up the following bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ••••••••••••••"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::••••••••••••:user/••••••••••••"
            },
            "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Still, when trying to delete an object in the bucket, I get

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteObject operation: Access Denied
```

I've been reading other answers ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75767568/cant-delete-objects-from-aws-s3-bucket-that-usees-cloudfront-distribution)) related to the subject, but none seems to help, as my `DeleteObject` policy is set on both the IAM user and the bucket.

Comment: You must have other policies that deny that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeleteObject permission is granted to an **IAM user**, but the delete error is experienced by a program using **boto3** client?

It seems that the principal is some program calling the delete api using boto3 and the above policy does not grant it the DeleteObject permission.
Suggestion: Grant the DeleteObject permission to a role and let the program calling in from boto3 assume that role.

Comment: I just noticed that S3FullAccess was granted to the IAM user. So @Marcin is correct, there may be a permissions boundary  defined, for example. That boundary can override the Full Access and reduce it to something that excludes DeleteObject access. Only those actions will be allowed which the existing policies and permissions boundary both allow.

Comment: No, I think you were actually right instead 
I was stupidly assuming that issuing some `boto3` commands in the shell of the client corresponding to the IAM user would still be done on behalf of the same user, but it's clearly not the case (late night programming...).
Making the IAM client really take care of that works indeed.

Comment: Good to hear that!